# display images at specific positions reading an external table uses tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplotstable, tikz-datavisualization

I'd like to define a set of positions and images in a data file,

```
x y filename
0 0 image/path/1.png
1 1 image/path/2.png
```

and use this data file to display the images on a 2D axis of a tikz environment. Potentially, I could add other formatting data like opacity or image size in the table.

It seams this kind of usage is beyond the scope of the documentation of the library, but I'm sure it's feasible. I just don't know how to address this.

I assume that applying the result in 3D is straightforward. If not, I would really be grateful to have also a 3D version.

Answer (score 2):

Here is one way.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfplotstableread[col sep=space]{
x y filename
0 0 example-image-a
1 1 example-image-b
1 0 example-image-c
0 1 example-image-duck
}{\mytable}
\pgfplotstablegetrowsof{\mytable} 
\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\NumRows}{\pgfplotsretval-1} 
\typeout{\NumRows}
\foreach \X in {0,...,\NumRows} 
{\pgfplotstablegetelem{\X}{x}\of{\mytable}
\edef\myx{\pgfplotsretval}
\pgfplotstablegetelem{\X}{y}\of{\mytable}
\edef\myy{\pgfplotsretval}
\pgfplotstablegetelem{\X}{filename}\of{\mytable}
\edef\myfilename{\pgfplotsretval}
\typeout{\myx,\myy,\myfilename}
\node at (\myx,\myy) {\includegraphics[width=8mm]{\myfilename}};
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The 3d case is analogous.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
\begin{document}
\tdplotsetmaincoords{70}{70}

\begin{tikzpicture}[tdplot_main_coords]
\pgfplotstableread[col sep=space]{
x y z filename
0 0 1 example-image-a
1 1 2 example-image-b
1 0 3 example-image-c
0 1 4 example-image-duck
}{\mytable}
\pgfplotstablegetrowsof{\mytable} 
\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\NumRows}{\pgfplotsretval-1} 
\typeout{\NumRows}
\foreach \X in {0,...,\NumRows} 
{\pgfplotstablegetelem{\X}{x}\of{\mytable}
\edef\myx{\pgfplotsretval}
\pgfplotstablegetelem{\X}{y}\of{\mytable}
\edef\myy{\pgfplotsretval}
\pgfplotstablegetelem{\X}{z}\of{\mytable}
\edef\myz{\pgfplotsretval}
\pgfplotstablegetelem{\X}{filename}\of{\mytable}
\edef\myfilename{\pgfplotsretval}
\begin{scope}[canvas is xz plane at y=\myy,transform shape]
 \node at (\myx,\myz) {\includegraphics[width=8mm]{\myfilename}};
\end{scope}
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Is it possible to have it inside an axis ? I'm display multiple of those "scatter" one next to the other and it would be easier with one "axis" environment per scatter.